# is it possible to access data in a specific window of browser?(Browser is embedded in desktop java application)

Tags: java, browser

I am creating an application in which there will be multiple windows within the browser- many forms will be  opened for submission in a single window and each form's target window will be one of the many windows available...

I want to be able to access the response of each form submission, i.e. I want to access content in each window from code in the desktop java application.

Please clarify the following for me-

(1) Is the above scenario achievable in a desktop java application?
(2) Which java browser component should I use, that enables me to access content of a window in the embedded browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [SWT Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html) component and then add a listener to intercept links. You can find an example [here](http://deanoneclipse.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/intercepting-links/). This of course will only work if your forms data would be passed using GET params appended to the url.

Comment: Kris, I want the form to be submitted to its action, in the form definition i am defining a custom target window for that form, so that the response from server (to which form is submitted) is shown in the custom window... Now I want to access the content in this particular window (to check what the response message is...) Can I do this using SWT Browser? Can you point me to a good guide /tutorial on this? Thanks...